# How to get height of responsive div's background-image

Tags: css

I have a div with a background image. This div has some other dive inside, like my navigation.

I would like to have this div have the same height of the background image.

My tries have been:

```css
.bg {
  width: 100 %;
  display: inline - block;
}

.bg::after {
  background: url('/images/desktop2.png') no - repeat center top;
  background - size: 100 % auto;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z - index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="navigation"></div>
  <div>Other contents</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>First content</div>
  <div>
    <Second content</div>
      ...
  </div>
```

In this way I'm getting the bg div to have the image height, but the `container` div arrives inside the div background image.

I need the bg div to have just and only the navigation and Other contents.

After this div I need the container with its contents

Comment: Dyou mean you try to get .bg to have the same ratio size than it's background ?

Comment: sorry Hash, i cannot get your comment. I have a bg div and after a container div. I need the bg div to be as high as the background image, so that everything in the container goes after it

Comment: yes @G-Cyr, thanks

Comment: Maybe linking your bg image or at least share its width/height properties will help you :) At least we'll know the ratio needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use a pseudo and padding to expand height of your container to fit the known ratio of your background-image:

example

```css
.bg-ratio {
  background: url(https://baconmockup.com/1024/576) no-repeat red/* only to check ratio height */
  ;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* to see the floatting pseudo */
  font-size: 5vmax;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px black;
}

.bg-ratio:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  /* (576px / 1024px) x 100 */
}

body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-ratio">
  <header>content in here</header>
  <main>
    <p>play full page and resize window's width</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

**How to grow height of an element to match a ratio ?**

vertical margins or paddings in percentage value will be calculated from parent's width.  `padding-top : 100%` will be equal to parent's `width`. If set on a pseudo, an empty box will expand to be a square *(ratio 1:1 )*.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

> **`<length>`**
>
> Specifies a fixed width.
>
> **`<percentage>`**
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.
>
> Unlike margin properties, values for padding values cannot be negative. **Like margin properties**, **percentage values for padding properties refer to the width of the generated box's containing block**.

---

If the container span the whole screen, you may use `vw` units via `height` or `min-height` and drop the pseudo.

```css
.bg-ratio {
  background:
  url( https://baconmockup.com/1200/100) 
  no-repeat 
  red /* only to check ratio height */;
  background-size:100% auto;
  height:8.33vw;/* (100px / 1200px) x 100 */
}
body {
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="bg-ratio">
  <div>content in here</div>
</header>
<main>play full page and resize window's width</main>
```

Comment: Thanks this example it's clear but i'm still getting the header content UNDER the div with the bg image... The image is 1024x576 pixel

Comment: Okay, you want to include next content inside the bg container too ?

Comment: i'm trying to make a fiddle, basically it's <div class="bg"> <nav></nav><div class="header-content"></div>. Nav and header-content div should go with the bg image. With your example, don't know why, only <nav> is inside

Comment: With the fiddle it works as you said, so i think the problem is somewhere else, maybe in my bootstrap nav css... i will accept your answer cause it's correct, thanks

Comment: @besmart I updated the first snippet , you may run in it again to see if that is it :)